# Kotlin plugin error: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Getting an error while trying to run a gradle task. Can't figure out what else is required or what the error is about. The project I'm working on has several subprojects, so I have a main build.gradle. The error is for a subproject where I wanted to try Kotlin.

```
* Where: Build file '/home/oracle/bnc/KotlinHandler/build.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'KotlinHandler'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin']
   > Could not generate a proxy class for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.
```

Here is my build.gradle for the failing module (sub-project).

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Here is [Pastebin build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/vGi4x2Ak) which is quite big, because of all the tasks in it

Added --debug [output](https://pastebin.com/vJeF7kY3) after changing jdk to 1.8 and compile dependency to `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8`

Comment: please add `build.gradle` of KotlinHandler module

Comment: @AbhishekAryan, it's the one attached actually. I edited the post to make it clear

Comment: If this is your submodule level `build.gradle` then add your root level `build.graldle` file

Comment: @AbhishekAryan, I uploaded the main build.gradle on pastebin and attached a link to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

starting kotlin `1.1.2` JDK below 1.8 is not supported anymore by the `kotlin` compiler as in [1.1.2 blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/04/kotlin-1-1-2-is-out/#more-4945):

> The Kotlin compiler now requires JDK 8 to run. You shouldn’t notice any changes, because most other Java development tools such as Gradle and the Android toolchain also require JDK 8, so you almost certainly already have it installed. For code generated by the compiler, Java 1.6 compatibility is still the default, and we have no plans to drop support for generating Java 1.6 compatible bytecode.

Comment: Thank you @oshai, i figured that. Unfortunately i have to deal with jdk7 as it's the target jvm version

Comment: Its not totally related and you can see it in the blog post: when you compile you need at least JDK 8, but you can target bytecode to be in other language level such as 1.7. for example in gradle you will add the directive: `sourceCompatibility = 1.6`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I specified a path to JDK8 and it started working. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend that you accept it as the answer to help others.

Comment: Make sure gradle runs with the right JDK. In my case there are multiple JDKs on the box, so I ended up telling gradle which one to use as follows:
`gradlew :myTask -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because I was running gradle with java 1.7 and it looks like the plugin was compiled only for 1.8:

```
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin']
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:153)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
16:48:42.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at build_4u37tyfuy0k7d4zd8vsk5lx9d.run(build.gradle:17)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 63 more
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not generate a proxy class for class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:201)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:64)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.create(TaskFactory.java:115)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.TaskFactory.createTask(TaskFactory.java:77)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.createTask(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:101)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.createTask(DependencyAutoWireTaskFactory.java:39)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:62)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:97)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinTasksProvider.createKotlinJVMTask(TasksProvider.kt:26)
16:48:42.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor.doCreateTask(KotlinPlugin.kt:111)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor.doCreateTask(KotlinPlugin.kt:93)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSetProcessor.createKotlinCompileTask(KotlinPlugin.kt:83)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinSourceSetProcessor.<init>(KotlinPlugin.kt:56)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.Kotlin2JvmSourceSetProcessor.<init>(KotlinPlugin.kt:101)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlugin.buildSourceSetProcessor$kotlin_gradle_plugin_main(KotlinPlugin.kt:302)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlugin.buildSourceSetProcessor$kotlin_gradle_plugin_main(KotlinPlugin.kt:295)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractKotlinPlugin$configureSourceSetDefaults$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:279)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractKotlinPlugin$configureSourceSetDefaults$1.execute(KotlinPlugin.kt:256)
16:48:42.744 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:110)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractKotlinPlugin.configureSourceSetDefaults(KotlinPlugin.kt:278)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.AbstractKotlinPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:269)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:306)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPlugin.apply(KotlinPlugin.kt:295)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:46)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinBasePluginWrapper.apply(KotlinPluginWrapper.kt:34)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:137)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 73 more
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/common/arguments/K2JVMCompilerArguments : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspectClass(ClassInspector.java:67)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.visitGraph(ClassInspector.java:51)
16:48:42.745 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.ClassInspector.inspect(ClassInspector.java:31)
16:48:42.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:260)
16:48:42.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.inspectType(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
16:48:42.746 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generateUnderLock(AbstractClassGenerator.java:95)
```

Related tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17866 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17297

Comment: I tried last night to install jdk8 on the box where I have issues, but it didn't help. Maybe I just missed something, gonna retry. My laptop though have jdk8 where all works fine

Comment: Try running with --stacktrace in addition to --debug to get a bit more info on how gradle failed.

Comment: I had the same problem.
Installing oracle-java8 and setting gradle to run with java 1.8 solved it for me. 
Thank you @DanielSilva

Comment: Yup, jdk8 specified in gradle.properties helped

Comment: Or you can specify on the command line:
`gradlew :myTask -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0`

Answer (score 1):

If you're still receiving this error despite:

- Setting the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your JDK8 installation.
- Changing `sourceCompatibility` in your `build.gradle` file.
- Pointing to JDK8 in your `gradle.properties` file.

It's possible that you're running an old version of gradle.

I was receiving this error on gradle `version 3.2`, but upgrading to `version 5.1` fixed the error for me.

You can download the latest release from [Gradle's Website](https://gradle.org/releases/).

More info [here](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript/issues/180).

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my ass. Normally I am working with close-to-latest versions, but I had this weird setup which specifically downloaded an old version without me noticing... Already cost me hours...

Comment: @JHorseman Glad I could help. I also wasted a lot of time with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `jcenter()` repo in `buildscript` repositories and update kotlin version.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

  }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

If you're targeting JDK 7 or JDK 8, you can use extended versions of the Kotlin standard library which contain additional extension functions for APIs added in new JDK versions. Instead of kotlin-stdlib, use one of the following dependencies:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7"
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8"
```

Comment: Switch to Java 1.8, If still you get error then Run with --debug option to get more log output. and put all your error log here

Comment: updated the question with `--debug` output after switching to jdk8

Comment: also an interesting thing is that the same configuration seems working on my local laptop, but when deployed on the server, it doesn't work. I thought it was b/c of jdk, but updated to jdk8 still not working

Comment: Had to specify jdk8 path in gradle.properties and it started working